# no such element: Unable to locate element: "Issue"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button "Reserve" in a webpage but it is showing the above error when I try with the below code

The element can be able to identify when it is inspected but during web driver run it is showing no such element

[issue on click "Reserve" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPg81.jpg)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(100));
            
By listElementLocator = By.cssSelector("ul.resortsSpecifications-anchorSticky li:nth-child(4)");

// Find the 2nd element using the nth-child selector
WebElement secondElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Reserve']"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(secondElement));
// Perform an action on the element (e.g., click)
secondElement.click();
```

I tried the above code with selenium java

Comment: its probably because youre not waiting for the element when you do driver.find. Just add By.cssSelector to elementToBeClickable and it should be fine. ```wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[value='Reserve']")```

Comment: Also, you want to use cssSelector or xpath? because it looks like its xpath so it should be ```//input[@value="Reserve"]```